# How to restart Kivy Animation

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a simple countdown timer, i want  to be able to restart it on the Button click, right now it won't start other, i just  can not get it right. What am i missing here?

the KV

```
<RootWidget>:
    #:import randint  random.randint
    orientation: "vertical"
    CountDownLbl:
        id: anim_label
        text: "{0:.3f}".format(float(self.startCount - self.angle / 360))
        font_size: 30
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0,1,0
            Line:
                circle:self.center_x, self.center_y, 90, 0, self.angle % 360
                width: 30
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: "Start"
        on_press: anim_label.start()
```

and the code

```
COUNT=1

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class CountDownLbl(Label):
    startCount = COUNT
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CountDownLbl, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def start(self):
        self.startCount = COUNT
        self.anim = Animation(angle=360 * self.startCount,  duration=self.startCount)
        self.in_progress = True
        self.anim.start(self)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first animation animates the `angle` property to `360`, and further animations try to animate the `angle` property to `360` again, which results in no actual animation. The fix is to increment your `COUNT` after each animation, like this:

```
def start(self):
    global COUNT
    self.startCount = COUNT
    self.anim = Animation(angle=360 * self.startCount,  duration=self.startCount)
    self.in_progress = True
    self.anim.start(self)
    COUNT += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own quesstion, Kudos to John.

Thank's John Anderson. This is the final version. Most important, i am updating text in a function instead of doing it in the KV, and second the increment has to be by TIMER value and not by 1.  Latest example can be found here https://github.com/vmindru/amb_pit_timer/blob/main/simple_timer.py

code

```
TIMER_DURATION = 5

class CountDownLbl(Label):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    timer_duration = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CountDownLbl, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.anim_duration = self.timer_duration
        self.in_progress = False

    def start(self):
        if not self.in_progress:
            self.anim = Animation(angle=360 * self.anim_duration,  duration=self.timer_duration)
            self.in_progress = True
            self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.finish, on_progress=self.update_timer)
            self.anim.start(self)
            self.anim_duration += TIMER_DURATION

    def finish(self, animation, widget):
        widget.text = "FINISHED"
        self.in_progress = False

    def update_timer(self, animation, widget, progression):
        text = ((self.timer_duration * 60000)*(1-progression))/60000
        widget.text = "{0:.3f}".format(float(text))
```

kv

```
CountDownLbl:
    id: anim_label
    timer_duration: 5                 
    font_size: 30           
    text: "{}.000".format(self.timer_duration)
    canvas:
        Color:                                                                                                     
            rgb: 0,1,0                                                                                             
        Line:                                  
            circle:self.center_x, self.center_y, 90, 0, self.angle % 360
            width: 30
```